# ffmpeg разный результат кодирования из mp3 в ogg

Tags: ffmpeg, ogg

Конвертирую **mp3** в **ogg**:

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -f mp3 -i /tmp/file.mp3 -acodec libvorbis -f ogg /tmp/file.ogg

md5sum /tmp/file.ogg
```

Сначала имеем результат: 26b3273348e83c58dd265c488a23bd22 file.ogg

Если запустить эти строки заново, то получается уже другой результат: 4bc80d4ca3e1368f3d848ec5f45001d0  file.ogg

и так каждый раз.

Как можно конвертировать **mp3** в **ogg**, чтобы всегда получался одинаковый результат, соответственно одинаковое значение **md5**?
Возможно ли такое?